# spring @SessionAttributes and "Cannot create a session after the response has been committed"

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-mvc

I am trying to set and get a session attribute, but either I have misunderstood how it works or i've done something wrong.

Please could somebody explain why this doesn't work.

I have the following simple Spring Web MVC Controller

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("sessid")
@RequestMapping("sesstest")
public class SessTest 
{
    @RequestMapping("in")
    @ResponseBody
    public String in(ModelMap model){
        String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        model.addAttribute("sessid", uuid);
        return uuid;
    }

    @RequestMapping("out")
    @ResponseBody
    public String out(@ModelAttribute("sessid") String sesid){
        return sesid;
    }
}
```

This class should just set a session variable when calling /sesstest/in and then recall it when calling /sesstest/out

But It get the following exception when calling /in

(The stacktrace is shown on the console, the web output is OK)

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.doGetSession(Request.java:2872)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getSession(Request.java:2249)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getSession(RequestFacade.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes.getSession(ServletRequestAttributes.java:111)
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes.setAttribute(ServletRequestAttributes.java:161)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.support.DefaultSessionAttributeStore.storeAttribute(DefaultSessionAttributeStore.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.SessionAttributesHandler.storeAttributes(SessionAttributesHandler.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelFactory.updateModel(ModelFactory.java:232)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.getModelAndView(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:782)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

*Thanks!*

Comment: hmm . does this help you . http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/110543-redirectattributes-cannot-create-a-session-after-the-response-has-been-committed

Comment: OK, thanks. having property read that article again I understand what the issue is: Direct access to the outputstream commits the response.  I have removed @ResponseBody and used a page template and it works. I will raise this as a potential bug/issue and then answer my question with the respose or workaround.

Comment: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12877

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Officially this "works as designed".

In this scenario, the various workarounds are:

1. Manually start a session
2. Use a filter to ensure a session is
   present
3. Use a view render from the model.

See Rossen's clear response here: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12877

> The scenario is somewhat unusual since typically model attributes are used for rendering with views (e.g. HTML template). For @ResponseBody only the return value is used to render the response. That said the use of @ResponseBody doesn't preclude the use of @SessionAttributes. The error has to do with trying to create the session for the first time too late. Normally the use of something like Spring Security with a Filter to store authentication in the session ensures there is always an HTTP session. In the absence of that you could add your own Filter or HandlerInterceptor that simply calls request.getSession(true). That's enough to ensure a session is present.

Can't argue with that.